# cant start new project in android studio showing IDE error

Tags: java, android, ide

I am using android studio 2.1.3 till yesterday it was working good.

Now I create new project after finish button it don't show anything it just

> IDE internal error exception in android support plugin .. disable
>   plugin support..

I re installed plugin..and added new **genymotion**. But I cant create new project.

I am new new to android and i searched about this error but no solution worked.

Comment: Try re installing Studio, check for the path of SDK and Java jdk

Answer (score 1):

1.Go to location in **C:\Program files\Android\Android Studio\bin\idea.properties**

2.Open the **idea.properties** file via any text editor

3. Add the following code to **disable.android.first.run=true**

4.Save as file on **desktop**

5.Go to the **C:\Program files\Android\Android Studio\bin**

6.paste the file which we save as on **desktop**

7.Now replace **idea.propeties** file.

Done...!

Now Start Android Studio....!

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me go to C:\Users\offer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk and delete SDKplatformtools and reinstall SDK platform tools from the link below https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html

[[if you can't find appdata folder  go to view on top left of the file explorer and click tick mark on hidden items ]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spuAv.png)

If am wrong please correct me